# TYPO3 Autocleanup for compressed JavaScript and CSS files in typo3temp/compressor

Tags: javascript, css, compression, typo3, min

is there an existing task or way in TYPO3 to remove old compressed JavaScript and CSS files? The folder typo3temp/compressor grows over time and contains several Gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

For all folders and files beyond `typo3temp/` applies: you can delete them and TYPO3 will recreated them if neccessary.

so you could install a basic cron-job cleaning your special directory or use a scheduler task.
There is a scheduler job "Caching framework garbage collection" which might be useful.